# Question Regarding Portable Ubuntu on Flash Disk

Tags: boot, usb, portable

I'm currently trying to install Ubuntu on my Flash Disk. I have been successful in installing and using rufus to put the OS on the Flash Disk. What I'm worried about is when installing Ubuntu, it asks me the installation type (erase disk and install ubuntu or something else). It says that it doesn't detect any other operating systems. Does that mean I can erase disk and install ubuntu without deleting everything on my PC (Windows 10)? I'm sorry if this question is bad, has been answered already, or doesn't have much details. Sorry and thanks in advanced!

Edit 1:
I'm installing Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Edit 2:
Sorry for not mentioning this. I'm using a pc that has Windows 10 on it's hard disk. I'm currently trying to install ubuntu on a usb that's connected to said pc.

Comment: Erase disk and install, does what it says. If that disk contained windows before hand, it'll be wiped & won't exist anymore. If your windows 10 was not cleanly closed (ie. fast boot was enabled, or hibernated) it may not show partitions on it, so be very careful.  You haven't mentioned your release of Ubuntu, so my details are *generic*. I personally explore the disk & create my plan, then use *something else* so I can setup my partitions myself. As I prefer `gparted` for partitioning, I often use that to create my scheme, selecting pre-prepared partitions during the installation.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the response. For clarification, does the disk that you mention is the flash drive, or my computer hard disk?

Comment: Disk can be HDD, SSD (both internal, external) & flash drives (even compact flash, SD cards or any other block type media your machine can use).  I've done it with prior releases of Ubuntu, but not 20.04 sorry as I just use *live* media myself, or create *persistent* storage should I need a little more. I used to install to thumb-drive often many releases ago (*for use on borrowed hardware*), but I've no need to do that these days...  *I'd wait for advice from people who've done it more recently, ie. with 20.04*

Comment: @karel Thanks for the link, I think it answers my question clearly.

Comment: Several methods can be found on this page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step They range from complex to very easy. To be safe it is best to unplug your internal drive when installing to USB drive